# How to open a specific tab in windows form

Tags: c#

[image]

all these tab are created dynamically in windows form . I want to open specific tab page on button click.

For example when clicking on a button(button is not tab page button ,its some other execution button), i want to display tab3 .

I am able to get no of tab pages, but unable to open specific tab..

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tabcount = Main_tab.TabCount;
    MessageBox.Show(tabcount.ToString());     
}
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

  int tabcount = Main_tab.TabCount;

  for (int count = 0; count < class_new_tab.tab_count; count++)
        {
            Main_tab.SelectTab(count);

             //perform tab operation
       }    

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`TabControl.SelectTab` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecttab.aspx)

```
this.tabControl1.SelectTab(1); // by index 
this.tabControl1.SelectTab("tab3");  // by tabPageName
this.tabControl1.SelectTab(tabPage); // by tab page
```

Or

[`TabControl.SelectedIndex` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx)

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1; //Selects second tab of the tab control
```

or

[`TabControl.SelectedTab` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx)

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a try/catch to catch the [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it through its index and call its methods for showing.

```
Main_tab.GetControl(index_of_your_tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the tabs under `Controls` of the `TabControl`.

Use `Find` to find the specific tab by name

```
Main_tab.SelectedTab = (TabPage)Main_tab.Controls.Find("tab3", searchAllChildren: false).First();
```

Comment: hi Dirk Boer, actually my question got edited wrongly, can you just help me in the above question now.

Comment: ehm.. as far as I understand your question correctly, the answer would still hold :)

While debugging just look into Main_tab.Controls and you'll see that the different TabPages are there.